# Check a script/program version in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm developing a script in Python 2.7. I want to make sure that the script is always up to date via github.
What I've tried is to create a file on github where I put the latest version number in and then in the python script I download that file and compare it with the version number of the program. This is my current script but it doesn't really work:

```
import sys
import os
import urllib
current_version = """1.4"""
print ("\a")
print ("Checking for latest verion..")
urllib.urlretrieve ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[myname]/[myproject]/master/version_latest", "version_latest")
version = open('version_latest', 'r').read()
if version == current_version:
    vlatest = "1"
else:
    vlatest = "2"

if vlatest == 2:
    print ("Please get the latest version of this program here:")
    print ("https://github.com/[myname]/[myproject]")
    print ("You can't use the program without it!")
    print ("\a")
    os.system("start https://github.com/[myname]/[myproject]")
    raw_input("Press enter to exit")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print ("You have the latest verion! Program will start automaticly!")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're comparing `vlatest` (which is a string) to the number `2`. Your `if` will always enter the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
    `if vlatest == 2`
To
    `if vlatest == "2"`

You are using different types, so they are not equal.
Use the same type and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

What error is coming.
However, what i can see is that you are assigning version no as string and checking it as integer in your if condition.
So, either convert it in to int by **int()** method or convert your integer to string by **str(2)** # 2 is your version no.

**Alternative Way:**

However, you can simply do one thing, just name the python script in such a way that it also contains version no too, something like parsing_1_4.py if version no is 1.4. By this, you don't need to open your script, just check the name of python file, parse the version no & compare it with the version no stored in your file. if they are equal, good, else update the script and note to update the script name too(New Version No.).